# in the main view after i am trying to wrote first name in another view it not apears in the main view

Tags: ios

the app are not work i am trying to enter a first name but it isnt appears in the main view

```
#pragma IBAaction

-(IBAction)DoneButton:(id)sender;
{


    Customer *newCustomer=[[Customer alloc]init];    

    newCustomer.firstName=self.firstNameTextField.text;
    newCustomer.LastName=self.LastNameTextField.text;

    [self.delegate addCustomerViewControllerDidSave:self newCustomer:newCustomer];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

-(IBAction)CancelButton:(id)sender
{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Do you have the Done button linked to to the IBAction in you .xib file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just taking a stab in the dark here given the little information given. But either your Done button isn't wired to the DoneButton: method in interface builder, or self.delegate isn't set like you think it if.

Either way, the debugger or a couple of NSLog statements should help shed some light on the issue.

Comment: So what i should do if after i wired to the button. what does the delegate in mean?